# How to access Blazor WASM session storage in Program.cs?

Tags: c#, token, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to implement a Microservices project with a Blazor WASM front end. I am using Google as my identity provider, and have successfully setup authentication for the front end.

However, with the next step I want to send over my `id_token` and **not my** `access_token` to my Gateway API in order to confirm the user is authenticated when they are hitting my endpoints. I've read the documentation provided by Microsoft and there is no guidance on this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0

I am trying to accomplish this myself by configuring the HTTP client at  `Program.cs`, but can't figure out how to grab the `id_token` from the session storage.

```
 builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GatewayApi", async client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["GatewayServiceConfiguration:BaseUrl"]);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_GOES_HERE);
            });
```

I've only seen Blazor session storage available via razor pages, and never in the startup itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the ProtectedLocalStorage? How are you accessing the Local Storage in your razor pages?

Comment: "Session storage" usually means something completely different from "cookie storage" or "local storage".  Could you clarify exactly what storage you're using?

Comment: I have been using Blazored Session Storage https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage
And yes, I mean "local storage" not cookie storage.

Comment: Maybe a Typed Client would be a better approach as you could inject the session storage service into the constructor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients

Comment: @MisterMagoo You're right that seems to be the best way to go about it for now. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept it.